# How do I apply changes to a data object within a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

If I have the following:

```
var dataContainer = [
                       { id : 1, value : 5, qty : 73, orders: 7 },
                       { id : 2, value : 6.15, qty : 212, orders: 49},
                       { id : 3, value : 12.11, qty : 29, orders : 6} 
                    ];
```

How do I update the value of the object using JavaScript? I have been trying the following:

```
function UpdateValues(passedId) {
    var thisData = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < dataContainer.length; i++ ) {
      thisData = dataContainer[i];
       if (thisData.id == passedId) {
           // I am updating the values in thisData 
       }
     }
     // Not sure what to do here in order to get thisData values back into dataContainer

 }
```

So I tried to pop the `dataContainer[i]` and push the `thisData` back on but this didn't work. Unless I'm doing it incorrectly? What should I be doing here? I appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't need to "get `thisData` values back into `dataContainer`" -- they never left. Modifying the objects does not destroy `dataContainer`'s references to them.

Comment: ok. thanks apsillers...must be something else wrong i did but at least i know. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function UpdateValues(passedId, prop, newValue) {
    var thisData = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < dataContainer.length; i++ ) {
        thisData = dataContainer[i];
        if (thisData.id == passedId) {
            thisData[prop] = newValue;
        }
    }
}

//Change qty to 99999 for object with index of 1
UpdateValues(1, "qty", 99999);
```

I've added a fiddle that prints out the result as well: http://jsfiddle.net/4UH9e/

Comment: yeah that is it...i had a mistake with the id value going in, plus that is easier than i thought. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
function UpdateValues(passedId) {
    var thisData = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < dataContainer.length; i++ ) {
        var data = dataContainer[i];
        for (i in data) {
            thisData[i] = data[i];
        }
        if (thisData.id == passedId) {
           //Update the values in thisData. 
        }
    }
    //You still have the original data in dataContainer
}
```